# How to overwrite connection strings in WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: .net, testing, integration-testing, xunit, .net-8.0

I have an API that I would like to make integration tests for. I have a Program.cs and a custom made Startup.cs which is basically a static class containing extension methods to `WebApplicationBuilder` to mimic the .NET behavior prior to .NET 6.

```cs
// Program.cs
WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging()
    .ConfigureServices()
    .Build()
    .Initialize()
    .ConfigurePipeline()
    .Run();

// Startup.cs
public static class Startup
{
    public static WebApplicationBuilder ConfigureLogging(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        // Configure logging
        return builder;
    }

    public static WebApplicationBuilder ConfigureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var services = builder.Services;
        var configuration = builder.Configuration;

        services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
            var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
            dataSourceBuilder.EnableDynamicJson();
            options.UseNpgsql(dataSourceBuilder.Build());
        });

        return builder;
    }

    public static WebApplication ConfigurePipeline(this WebApplication app)
    {
        // Register middleware
        app.UseRouting();
        app.MapControllers();
        return app;
    }

    public static WebApplication Initialize(this WebApplication app)
    {
        // Resolve DbContext and call .Migrate()
        return app;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a custom `WebApplicationFactory<>` and override some stuff in there, such as the database that will be used. I am using the [Testcontainers.PostgreSql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Testcontainers.PostgreSql) NuGet package and my factory looks like this:

```cs
public class MyFactory : WebApplicationFactory<IAssemblyMarker>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly PostgreSqlContainer _postgreSqlContainer = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
        .WithUsername("username")
        .WithPassword("password")
        .WithDatabase("mydb")
        .Build();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
        });

        // If I use ConfigureTestServices, the test first calls ConfigureTestServices,
        // then ConfigureServices, and then Startup.ConfigureServices (the extension method)
        //builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var connectionString = _postgreSqlContainer.GetConnectionString();

            services.RemoveAll<AppDbContext>();
            services.RemoveAll<IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>>();
            services.RemoveAll<IDataTypeBuilder>();

            services.AddSingleton<IDataTypeBuilder, NpgsqlDataTypeBuilder>();
            services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString)
                {
                    Name = "IntegrationTests App"
                };
                options.UseNpgsql(dataSourceBuilder.Build());
            });
        });
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _postgreSqlContainer.StartAsync();
    }

    async Task IAsyncLifetime.DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _postgreSqlContainer.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

The problem is, calling `_myFactory.CreateClient()` will always throw an exception because the connection string in my `appsettings.json` is defined for my local PostgreSQL container, which is naturally down for the integration tests. I did try setting breakpoints and I have a question: Why does my test method (after calling CreateClient) enter the `WebApplicationFactory<>.ConfigureServices` (or ConfigureTestServices - I can't seem to find what the difference between the two is) and then the `Startup.ConfigureServices`? What happens then is that the `PostgreSqlContainer` connection string doesn't play a role in my tests at all, but the test methods try to connect to my database that is defined in my `appsettings.json`.

What is the correct fix and workaround for this? Could the custom Startup class be the problem (since `Startup.ConfigureServices` is a custom extension method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find a "workaround" (no idea if it should be done this way, though). I believe because my `AppDbContext` is registered using `AddPooledDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>` that I have not removed all service registrations using `services.RemoveAll<>` in my `WebApplicationFactory.ConfigureWebHost` inside `builder.ConfigureTestServices` / `builder.ConfigureServices` (I still do not know what the difference between the two would be), so the `AppDbContext` is registered in my custom `Startup` class with pre-existing appsettings.json configuration and AFTER that, I try to re-register the `DbContextFactory` in my `MyFactory`.

So, my workaround so far is to remove `ConfigureTestServices` and `ConfigureServices` from my `MyFactory : WebApplicationFactory` altogether and call `ConfigureAppConfiguration` which allows me to remove any `IConfiguration` sources and define my own `Dictionary<>` which would have my custom (integration-test specific) values for the app configuration.

```cs
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
{
    var configuration = new Dictionary<string, string?>
    {
        ["ConnectionStrings:Database"] = _postgreSqlContainer.GetConnectionString(),
    };

    builder.Sources.Clear();
    builder.AddInMemoryCollection(configuration);
});
```

The result of doing this is that when my `Startup.ConfigureServices` is called by my `Program` class, the `IConfiguration` it uses has ONLY the key-value pairs that I have defined above, so the connection string that it tries to use is basically pre-set by my integration test `MyFactory`.

I will mark this question as Answered. In case anyone has a better answer or explanation in the future, feel free to post them here.